# При каком условии равносторонний треугольник можно поместить в квадрат?

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Пусть есть квадрат со стороной `a` и равносторонний треугольник со стороной `b`.

Представим квадрат как некую дырочную область на земле в которую могут опускаться плоские формы (равносторонний треугольник в нашем случае).

При каком условии можно в него поместить этот треугольник?

Правила вписывания абсолютно любые, треугольник при этом можно поворачивать и перемещать как угодно в пространстве.

Comment: Но задача остается двумерной? Или треугольник можно поставить на ребро?

Comment: @Igor треугольник можно перемещать и поворачивать как на плоскости так и в пространтсве - тоесть задача получается 3 мерная в этом смысле, а дырочная область не изменна

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> При каком условии можно в него поместить этот треугольник ?

`(a * sqrt(2)) >= (b * sqrt(3) / 2)`,

где

`a * sqrt(2)` - диагональ квадрата - *максимальная* проекция квадрата как отрезка,

`b * sqrt(3) / 2` - высота треугольника - *минимальная* проекция треугольника как отрезка.

Comment: а откуда это условие ? )) хотелось бы каких нибудь пояснений если не трудно

Comment: так немного яснее, но почему мы сравниваем именно диагональ квадрата с высотой треугольника ?

Comment: @ampawd обратите внимание на слова "максимальный" и "минимальный" в ответе

Comment: а если диагональн квадрата равняется высоте треугольника как тогда можно поместить ?

Comment: @ampawd пытаюсь понять Ваш последний вопрос - и не могу. Вырежите из картона равносторонний треугольник, а в другом листе - квадратную дырку так, чтобы `b = 1.633 a`. И попробуйте запихнуть один в другой.

Comment: ок спасибо за пояснения

Comment: @Igor, наверное, всё-таки строго больше... если они равны, то они равны и одно в другое никак не пролезет

Comment: @Isaev Возможно. Зависит от того, что автор понимает под словом "поместить".

Answer (score 2):

Задача просто вписать треугольник в квадрат на плоскости все-таки чуть интереснее, хотя и школьная геометрия та же.
[image: равносторонний треугольник в квадрате]
Исходное предположение - углы альфа и бета должны быть равны. При увеличении угла альфа должен уменьшиться угол бета, и треугольник перестает быть равносторонним.

Comment: Т.е. α=β=(90-60)/2=15°, а возможность вписать треугольник в квадрат будет сохраняться до тех пор, пока b <= a/cos(15°)

Answer (score 0):

Если считать, что плоский треугольник это призма с высотой 1 точка (просто про высоту плоских фигур в задаче ничего не сказано) то треугольник влезет в "дырочную область" при условии если высота треугольника меньше диагонали квадратного сечения.

```
(a * sqrt(2)) > (b * sqrt(3) / 2)
```

А если эти значения будут равны, то треугольник уже не влезет. Это я вам как инженер говорю.

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо, чтобы все углы треугольника лежали на разных сторонах квадрата, то равносторонний треугольник получится вписать в квадрат только при соблюдении соотношений сторон:
a<=b<=a/0.9659
Если же допустить возможность, что 2 стороны треугольника будут "лежать" на сторонах квадрата, то главное условие - b<=a/0.9659